# Checking FTP server support in a Bluetooth device from an android app

Tags: android, bluetooth, ftp, ftp-server, obex

I need to check whether on a `Bluetooth` device FTP server is supported or not from my `android app`.

I can tell whether a `BluetoothDevice` is a Classic or LE or Dual from it. But how to tell whether it supports `FTP server` - it allows us to browse through the device's file structure.

Need help. all other `Obex` implementations are in older versions. Need help in the new ones

Comment: You mean an FTP server using bluetooth? Do they exist? Using the same protocol?

Comment: yup they do exist.